# Two separated links in bootstrap navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Look at this bootstrap navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>      
      </ul>     

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I want to have two links at the same time in a `li`. This is what I need but is not in suitable shape. The plus icon should be beside the link text in the demo.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/1443/)

Comment: Curious, why do you need them in the same <li>? Would need nothing custom if you put each in it's own

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#gotosite"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/1448/)**

But if this doesn't fit your requirements you can use this CSS over your original code

```
.nav>li>a {

display: inline-block;

}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/1445/)**

Comment: works, though i am guessing there is too much space between the links

Comment: You can also play with the space between the element border and the element content. Just add `padding: 10px 10px;` to the above CSS